# sendMessage to a hidden window did not work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, sendmessage

i want to send a click message on button of a window that it's caption is "Form1" and button's caption is "button1" here is my code:

i checked this handles by SPY++ seems correct..

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <conio.h>

    int main()
    {
     while(1)
     {
       HWND HWin, btn;
       HWin = FindWindowExA(NULL,NULL,NULL,"Form1");
       btn = FindWindowExA(HWin,0,NULL,"button1");
       SendMessage(btn,BM_CLICK,0,0);
       _getch();
      }
    }
```

this code worked well and every thing is good... but when "Form1" is set to hidden sendMessage seems not work! Why???

notice that `FindWindowExA(...)`  still return same handle while "Form1" is hidden, and is equal with previous (when is shown)

setting hidden/show of "Form1" is done by this lines:

to shown:

```
    ShowWindow(HWin,SW_SHOW);
```

to hidden:

```
    ShowWindow(HWin,SW_HIDE);
```

i'm running on VS 2010

i want to know if sendMessage not work on hidden window is there other way to do that??

thanks All

Comment: Per the [`BM_CLICK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/bm-click) documentation: "*If the button is in a dialog box and the dialog box is not active, the BM_CLICK message might fail.*" Why would you expect sending a click (a *visual*-oriented action) to a *hidden* window would succeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are judiciously checking to make sure that your `FindWindow` calls are not returning NULL when the window is hidden before executing the message passing code.

Assuming you are getting valid HWNDs returned from FindWindow, instead of `BM_CLICK` message sent to the button itself.  Try sending a `WM_COMMAND` message to the parent window.

```
if (HWin && btn)
{
    LONG ctrlId = GetWindowLong(btn, GWL_ID);
    SendMessage(HWin, WM_COMMAND, MAKEWORD((WORD)ctrlId, BN_CLICKED), (LPARAM)btn);
}
```

If the application itself is in a state where it's not expecting click notifications while hidden, you risk some really weird behavior.

I would think this would work for a win32 app or dialog.  Not sure about a .NET forms app.